# Assoc command not working in Windows 7

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, command-prompt

I am having a need where I want to change the default associated program for a particular file extension from the command prompt. The file that I have is of an extension .ChangeSetInfo which is basically an xml file. I want to associate "Xml Notepad 2007" as the default program for this type of extension. For that I have written a small batch file. The content is as follows

```
assoc .CHANGESETINFO= 
ftype CHANGESETINFO File= 
assoc .CHANGESETINFO=CHANGESETINFO File
ftype CHANGESETINFO File="C:\Program Files\XML Notepad 2007\XmlNotepad.exe"
```

When I execute this batch file then it seems that everything is working fine as I am not getting any error message. But after that when I double click on the file with extension .ChangeSetInfo then the xmlnotepad program is launched but the file is not getting open. But the file is shown properly if I use the File Open option from the Xml Notepad window.

Can somebody please help me on this?

I am using Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1. I am also using the administrator account on this system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `assoc .doc` on your system, it should return something like `Word.Document.8`. Typing `ftype Word.Document.8` produces something like

```
Word.Document.12="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\WINWORD.EXE" /n "%1" /o /o "%u"
```

The "%1" indicates that it should open the file passed as the first parameter on the command line. The quotes around it make sure that any embedded spaces in that filename are not interpreted as command separators.

Therefore, the solution to your issue would be to change the `ftype` statement to do the same:

```
ftype CHANGESETINFO File="C:\Program Files\XML Notepad 2007\XmlNotepad.exe" "%1"
```

As a note: If it were me, I'd change both `assoc` and `ftype` to use `ChangeSetInfoFile`, both because it's easier to read and to remove the embedded space between "CHANGESETINFO" and "File".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes you are right that I need to add the "%1" argument for the command to work. But I would also like to add that the batch file is not allowing to add the "%1". It shows " " in the registry afterwards. So I quit the idea of using a .bat file and currently I am executing the commands directly in the cmd.exe and working fine for me now. Anyways thanks a lot for your reply. This was really helpful.

Comment: Thanks, the double quotes around the argument is the clincher.

Comment: I would use `"%~1"` to remove any potentially existing quotes to avoid quoting twice. (and from [Octaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6474367/octaviour), who has not enough rep to add a comment): *for  use in a batchfiles escape the `%` with another `%`: `"%%1"`*